# Angular get all filenames inside a specifc folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Inside my Angular app i i want to liste all files names inside assets folder.

So that i want to use this npm library : **list-files-in-dir**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-files-in-dir

Sso i ve this service inside my angular app :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {listFiles} from 'list-files-in-dir';
    @Injectable()
    export class ConfigService {
      files: any;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      getFilesFromFolder(){
        listFiles('assets/')
        .then(files => {
            // do what ever you want with the file paths
            this.files = files
            console.log(this.files)
        }
       }
     }
```

but when calling it i get this error :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: ENOENT: No such file
> or directory., '/assets' Error

i ve done a stackblitz snippet for this :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-jsonfile-data

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: What file system are you expecting to be able to read from your Angular app? I assume this is a normal Angular app running in a browser?

Comment: When running in the browser is not possible to access the file system.

Comment: Any simple alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You should

1) Add an server API that return file list.

2) Or you can write a script to gen file list to a json file, and dynamic load by angular

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the filesystem in angular directly because some day you might deploy your code and then the code runs in a browser.

If you create a desktop application in combination with [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) then you can access the desktop file system via [node.js filesystem api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Angular has the concept of `environments` to store configs where you can differ configs between prod and dev, have a look at the [Angular build guide docs](https://angular.io/guide/build).

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://my-api-url'
};
```

For only plain config settings i recommend to create a plain `ConfigService` and just hold the data as `const` in there.

If you prefer to load the data from json files you can follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110817/load-config-json-file-in-angular-2/44398367) for Load Config JSON File In Angular 2.